# There is delay in loading CSS when site first loads

Tags: gatsby

So, I am working on a website. It is fully developed but the issue is that there is delay in CSS when site loads. I can see unstyled components and messy HTML. Can anyone point out the issue?

Site: https://www.ltlsurfcharters.com/

Thanks

Comment: I've typically seen this happen with CSS-in-JS. From the Gatsby docs on [Enhancing Styles with CSS-in-JS](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/css-in-js/): `Keep in mind that styles aren’t applied until the JavaScript loads hence a plugin to extract the styles is necessary to prevent flash of unstyled content (FOUC).` How are you styling your Gatsby site? If CSS-in-JS, are you using the relevant SSR plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it was basically due to css files included in react helmet. I removed all files from there and imported all css files in my App component using the normal js import.